# How to use external javascript files in my web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a web page where I use HTML and jQuery. In the beginning I had everything in the same file like that :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>

        <script>
                Here goes my jquery ...
        </script>
    </head>  

    <body>
    <h1>Subscribe To Categories</h1>
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="category1">Category1<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="category2">Category2<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="category3">Category3<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="category4">Category4<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="category5">Category5<br><br>                 
    </form> 
    <button>Click me</button>   
</body>
```

Which is a simple checkbox page with trivial `jQuery`. As you can see I do 2 things: 
1) import jQuery with this line:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then write my script inside the `<script>` tags.

However I saw that I could keep my `JavaScript` and `CSS` in external files and simply import them to my project.

I created a `script.js` file and inside I put all my jQuery code. Then my HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Subscribe To Categories</h1>
        <form>
            <input type="checkbox" id="category1">Category1<br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="category2">Category2<br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="category3">Category3<br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="category4">Category4<br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="category5">Category5<br><br>                 
        </form> 
        <button>Click me</button>   
    </body>


</html>
```

As you see I import CSS and jQuery with these lines:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
```

and

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

However my jQuery doesn't work now... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you have the jquery import in your new solution ?

Comment: When i put it , then the line where i import the actual .js file gets "grey" , like is not a command of the language any more..anyway i did and again it doesnt work. I just added before i imported the .js file

Comment: open up your page in google chrome or firefox (with firebug), and look for errors :) in G Chrome go for right click and "inspect element" (anywhere on your page), new window will pop-up in right hand side of that new window on the bototm there will be red exclamation mark click on it and read your error. Thats "why".

Comment: It's obvious that you have to include jQuery before you can use it, isn't it? Make sure your `script.js` file is valid JavaScript, i.e. it should not contain the `<script>` tags. Also, [read this article about debugging JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: Each script import must be like this : `<script src='link.js'></script>`

Comment: dystroy you are completely right. I was forgetting to close the tag. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need both jQuery and your own script file referenced, in that order:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

*Note: In HTML 5 the `type` attribute is not required.*

Comment: The mistake was that i wasnt using the </script> tag for importing the jquery. So when i was trying to import the .js file after it , it was crashing. Thank you a lot sir. Now that i close the tag correctly works fine

Answer (score 0):

You still need to put the following line before your own script to include jQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Subscribe To Categories</h1>
        <form>
            <input type="checkbox" id="category1">Category1<br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="category2">Category2<br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="category3">Category3<br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="category4">Category4<br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="category5">Category5<br><br>                 
        </form> 
        <button>Click me</button>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you forgot to include jQuery in the second case. Simply add

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you probably included jquery wrong way to your script.js… But you can link two or more scripts, so why not to use:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```